# Transparently Rate Limiting ANY Connection that is Already In-Progress

Tags: debian, networkmanager, download, limit, traffic-shaping

Let's say I begin a large download, and (about an hour into it) I find that it is consuming too much of my overall bandwidth.

Is there any way to rate limit that particular connection "after the fact"? I've seen tools that will allow you to control a download's speed if you begin the download using those tools, but I'm interesting a way to rate limit a download of ANY connection (even if it is already in progress).

How can this be done?

Comment: If you're willing to explore, the Linux traffic control subsystem allows you to use ip address and ports in your filter expressions, which ought to allow you to target specific connections. The [wondershaper](https://github.com/magnific0/wondershaper) tool purports to support this, but it looks as if it may use incorrect syntax.

Comment: There's a [script](https://forums.plex.tv/t/limiting-bandwidth-per-user/108682) from 2015 to configure **tc** to limit a given IP address (for a plex server). I've not looked at it enough to say if it is what you want. Also you may not be using iptables these days.